# Compile gdb 13.1 with custom python installation cannot find -lpython3.11

Tags: python-3.x, makefile, gdb, ld, configure

I have python installed in `PYTHON_DIR`. This is on Linux RHEL7.

```
ls $PYTHON_DIR
bin include lib share
ls $PYTHON_DIR/lib
libpython3.11.so libpython3.11.so.1.0 libpython3.so pkgconfig python3.11
```

I download gdb 13.1 source code, extract it, create build-rhel7 dir and cd into it.

```
../configure --with-python=$PYTHON_DIR
make
```

It fails saying that there is `no usable python found at /path/to/python`

If I open `gdb/config.log` the error is:

```
configure:22632: gcc -std=gnu99 -o conftest -g O2 -I/path/to/python/include -I/path/to/python/include/python3.11 -I/path/to/python/include/3.11 conftest.c -lpython3.11 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lncursesw -lm -ldl  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.11
```

So the issue is the compilation will not look into `$PYTHON_DIR/lib`. Even if I add this path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, it won't look there and therefore won't find the libpython3.11.so.

How do I get it to look in the lib/ directory?

(I changed paths because this is an internal enterprise environments).

Comment: `--with-python` expects the python executable as argument, not a directory.

Comment: The answer to your problem is given by ssbssa.  But to follow up on the things you tried that didn't work, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not used by the linker to find libraries to link, so setting it is useless for your problem.  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used by the runtime to find libraries when you run the program.  To tell the linker where to find things, you would use the `-L` option to the link command line.  If you follow ssbssa's advice and pass the Python _interpreter_ program via `--with-python`, then it will be used to find the right library and link things properly.

Comment: Actually --with-python pointing to the directory containing bin/, lib/, include/, works. It find the correct binary and includes. Also the gdb page explaining configure options tells it can be the name of the directory in which python is installed. (I actually initially tried it like ssbssa said, no difference). How would I go about adding a -L option to the configure call?

Comment: Ok LDFLAGS did the trick. Thanks a lot!